# Proof that elements of a free generating set have infinite order.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I'm trying to show that elements of a free generating set $S$ have infinite order straight from the definition of a free group being generated by $S$.

The definition I'm using is that a group $F$ is freely generated by a subset $S$ of $F$ if for any group $\Gamma$ and any map $\phi : S\rightarrow \Gamma$ there is a unique homomorphism from $F$ to $\Gamma$ extending $\phi$.

Comment: Well, which definition is that? There are various ways to phrase it. Also, please make the question self-contained, so the question does not only appear in the title.

Comment: Edited my questions.

Comment: Hint: Let $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}$ and see what happens if a generator has finite order.

Comment: I'd can see we'd have a problem as integers have infinite order, but I can see quite how I'd use that to form an argument.

Comment: You should know that the image of an element of finite order itself has finite order.

Comment: Okay, yeah I was worried that as we could take any map something weird could happen..

Comment: Only the map from $S$ can be arbitrary. The map from $F$ to $\Gamma$ needs to be a homomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F$ be free with generating set $S$ and $s\in S$. Then the map $\phi\colon S\to\mathbb Z$, $x\mapsto 1$ extends to a homomorphism $F\to\mathbb Z$ that maps $s^n\mapsto n\ne0$ if $n\ne0$.